# Measure Bitmap Fonts with OpenGL (Windows)

Tags: opengl, fonts, bitmap

What is the 'correct' way to determine the 'pixel' length of bitmap fonts rendered in OpenGL? I'm using 2D ortho and the wglUseFontBitmaps() function to build font character lists in Windows. If I want to measure the size of my resultant text (for centering, formatting etc), what is the correct way to do this?

Should I be using the Win32 GDI GetTextExtent() API function, or is there a means of determining the current 'cursor' position within OpenGL? The glRasterPos functions sets the output position, and as each character is rendered, the output position automatically advances.. so is there a glGetRasterPos perhaps that I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't own the fonts; Windows GDI must provide the information. I showed how to do it right [in my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595772/painting-text-above-opengl-context-in-mfc). You need `GetCharABCWidths()` for the per-character widths and `GetTextMetrics()` for the heights. Look at my `for` loop over formattedString.GetLength(), which calculates the string width in pixels. Then you can use `glRasterPos2d()` to put the text in the right place.