# Painting Text above OpenGL context in MFC

Tags: opengl, mfc

I work on an MFC app containing OpenGL context.I am new to MFC that is why I am asking it.OpenGL works fine ,but when I want to draw a text above the 3D window using this code inside WindowProc:

```
        case WM_PAINT:

      hDC=BeginPaint(window,&paintStr);
      GetClientRect(window,&aRect);
      SetBkMode(hDC,TRANSPARENT);
      DrawText(hDC,L"He He I am a text on top of OpenGL",-1,&aRect,DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER);
      EndPaint(window,&paintStr);

      return 0;
```

it is shown beneath the OpenGL context.I can see it only when resizing the window as the OpenGL rendering pauses than.

Comment: where is the opengl rendering code ? should be in the WM_PAINT but I can't see it in your code excerpt...

Comment: @Felice Pollano: I guess it's called from the idle loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong and also harder than doing it all in OpenGL. To solve the problem of **adding text to an OpenGL-drawn window**, it's better to just make OpenGL draw the text. You can even use the exact same font you were using in MFC by creating a CFont instance when you handle WM_CREATE, selecting the font into the DC, and calling wglUseFontBitmaps, which will make a series of rasterized bitmaps that you can use with glCallLists. (While you're at it, call GetCharABCWidths and GetTextMetrics to determine the width and height of each glyph, respectively.)

```cpp
ABC glyphInfo[256]; // for font widths
TEXTMETRIC tm;  // for font heights

// create a bitmap font
CFont myFont;
myFont.CreateFont(
    16,                        // nHeight
    0,                         // nWidth
    0,                         // nEscapement
    0,                         // nOrientation
    FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
    FALSE,                     // bItalic
    FALSE,                     // bUnderline
    0,                         // cStrikeOut
    ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
    DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
    DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
    _T("Arial")                // lpszFacename
);

// change the current font in the DC
CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(hdc);

// make the system font the device context's selected font  
CFont *pOldFont = (CFont *)pDC->SelectObject (&myFont); 

// the display list numbering starts at 1000, an arbitrary choice  
wglUseFontBitmaps (hdc, 0, 255, 1000); 
VERIFY( GetCharABCWidths (hdc, 0, 255, &glyphInfo[0]) );
pDC->GetTextMetrics(&tm);

if(pOldFont)
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);

myFont.DeleteObject();
```

Then when you handle WM_PAINT, reset your matrices and use glRasterPos2d to put the text where you need it to go. I suggest calculating the exact width of your string using code similar to the one below if you want it to be horizontally centered.

```cpp
// indicate start of glyph display lists  
glListBase (1000); 

CRect r;
GetWindowRect(r);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, r.Width(), 0, r.Height());

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

CString formattedString;
formattedString.Format("Pi is about %1.2f", 3.1415);

int stringWidth=0; // pixels
for(int j=0; j < formattedString.GetLength(); ++j)
    stringWidth += glyphInfo[ formattedString.GetAt(j) ].abcA + glyphInfo[ formattedString.GetAt(j) ].abcB + glyphInfo[ formattedString.GetAt(j) ].abcC;

double textXPosition, textYPosition;
textXPosition = r.Width()/2-stringWidth/2; // horizontally centered
textYPosition = r.Height()/2-tm.tmHeight/2; // vertically centered

glRasterPos2d(textXPosition,textYPosition);

// this is what actually draws the text (as a series of rasterized bitmaps)
glCallLists (formattedString.GetLength(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (LPCSTR)formattedString);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
```

While the setup is annoying, you only have to do it once, and I think it's less frustrating than dealing with GDI. Mixing GDI and OpenGL is really asking for trouble, and OpenGL does a very good job of displaying text -- you get sub-pixel accuracy for free, among other benefits.

**Edit:** In response to your request for including GUI elements, I will assume that you meant that you want to have both OpenGL-drawn windows and also standard Windows controls (edit boxes, check boxes, buttons, list controls, etc.) inside the same parent window. I will also assume that you intend OpenGL to draw only part of the window, not the background of the window.

Since you said you're using MFC, I suggest that you create a dialog window, add all of your standard Windows controls to it, and then add in a CWnd-derived class where you handle WM_PAINT. Use the resource editor to move the control to where you want it. Effectively, you're making an owner-draw custom control where OpenGL is doing the drawing. So OpenGL will draw that window, and the standard MFC classes (CEdit, CButton, etc.) will draw themselves. This works well in my experience, and it's really not much different from what GDI does in an owner-draw control.

What if instead you want OpenGL to draw the background of the window, and you want standard Windows controls to appear on top of it? I don't think this is a great idea, but you can handle WM_PAINT and WM_ERASE for your CDialog-derived class. In WM_ERASE, call OpenGL to draw your 3D content, which will be overwritten by the standard Windows controls when WM_PAINT is called. Alternatively in WM_PAINT you could call OpenGL before calling CDialog::OnDraw, which would be similar.

Please clarify your statement "I want to add some 2s graphics overlay (like labels ,gui elements)" if you want me to write more.

Comment: Hi @user244795 while I agree that your answer solves the problem because I tried it already before the original goal of mine is the ability to draw windows content above the OpenGL.So here I just tried the text example .But if I want to add some 2s graphics overlay (like labels ,gui elements) ,should I also do all this inside OpenGL ? Sorry for such basic questions but I am trying to make my NOOB's way through all this.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code I assume the OpenGL rendering is called from a timer or as idel loop action. Naturally OpenGL execution will probably contain some clearing, thus taking anything else drawn with it.

Mixing GDI text drawing with OpenGL is not recommended, but can be done. But of course you then need to include that code into the OpenGL drawing function, too, placing all GDI operations after the buffer swap.

Comment: Not just buffer swap, but `glFlush` or `glFinish` is needed to synchronize.  Otherwise the GPU may still be processing commands and perform the swap at some future point, still overwriting the GUI output.

Comment: wglSwapBuffers implies a glFinish(); think about it, a buffer swap only makes sense if the OpenGL has finished rendering.

Comment: Then the mixed OpenGL/GDI scenario requires a `glFlush`.  `wglSwapBuffers` goes in the same pipeline as all the other OpenGL commands, it returns before the buffer swap takes place, and GDI commands issued after `wglSwapBuffers` could still be executed before the buffer swap.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.Still it doesn't help.On the question where I run the render loop.I have got a separate class which contains all the OpenGL stuff.I call MyOpenGLCalss::display() in inside WinMain message loop that submits the buffers and renders the 3d content.As @Felice noted may be I really have to transfer this call into WinProc WM_PAINT ?Also I don't call glFinish as I work with OpenGL 3.3 programmable pipeline.Another question:Can I in fact draw text using Windows API DrawText() to the context used by OpenGL? Can Several context be layered on top of each other in MFC ? Thanks.

Comment: Calling or not calling glFinish has nothing to do with programmable vs. fixed pipeline. glFinish blocks your program until all queued up OpenGL operations with visible effect are done. You can have multiple OpenGL render contexts of a single window, however only one of them can be active at a time in a thread. You should treat a window as a exclusive resource, i.e. all drawing calls must be context exclusive. Note that OpenGL contexts don't "layer". You can create subwindows of your OpenGL window, but they will not interact well with their parent.

Comment: Mixing GDI and OpenGL with the right care, but it's arcane and difficult to get right. The canonical way to render text in OpenGL windows is using OpenGL to render the text. Search the web and StackOverflow for "OpenGL text rendering", there is vast information on this topic.